# How do I implement these strong password requirements?

Tags: passwords

- No keyboard patterns. i.e. keys that are adjacent vertically or horizontally on a keyboard. For example, 'ZXCVBN123' should be rejected.
- No commonly used words and no words written backwards or disguised with special characters. For example 'Universe1' and 'Un1ver$e' should be rejected.

Comment: Gee, that's a tough one! :)

Comment: Why not just assign your own passwords to the users and not let them change them except by requesting a new password that you once again will create? I think users will be quite frustrated when the first say 10 or so passwords they attemt to choose won't pass and that they will be less frustrated if you just assign them some password even if it is impossible to remember...

Comment: I agree. But apparently it wouldn't take long to crack the examples I gave. http://howsecureismypassword.net/

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Although I don't think I'm in a position to change the requirements.

Comment: Try http://strongpasswordgenerator.com/ create a password of 10 characters it would according to you site take 58 years to crack. You could just use an algorithm like that

Comment: Well, that requirement doesn't sound that brilliant to me...but I may be wrong. 
Probably no user will be able to choose a safe password if they won't press say ten random keys (taking it that the definition of safe is the site you refer to), and to me that doesn't really seem like a free choice for the user...

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you need to define exactly what you want. What are keyboard patterns? Is 'jk' a keyboard pattern, or just 'jkl'? What's the shortest pattern there is? Is 'gy' a pattern? First you need to define what a pattern really.

Then you should make a list of all the available patterns (There aren't all that many. You have 36 starting points and 4 directions to go from each starting point). When you get a password, try to locate each of the patterns in it. Note that if you decide the shortest pattern is 3 letters long, you don't need to search for 4-letter patterns, all 4-letter patterns already contain 3-letter patterns.

As for words, that's easier, but first you need to make a list of all disallowed transformations ($->S, 1->i, etc...). Once you get a word, apply all the transformations and get yourself a 'normalized' word. Compare the normalized password against a dictionary of all legal words twice - the second time reverse the password.

You will probably need to do something a little more complicated than that, because you need to ignore numbers at the end of the word - *sometimes*. 1ncredible can be a substitute for 'incredible', although ncredible is not a word.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the code of http://howsecureismypassword.net you can see that the password is compared to a large array of usual passwords.

On the page threre is a reference to the page http://xato.net/passwords/more-top-worst-passwords/ which lists the top 10.000 most common passwords.

One approach would be to download that list and check the users passwords against it or at least some top 100 of them.